# C++ volatile required when spinning on boost::shared_ptr operator bool()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, shared-ptr, volatile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading)

I have two threads referencing the same `boost::shared_ptr`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Widget> shared;
```

On thread is spinning, waiting for the other thread to reset the `boost::shared_ptr`:

```
while(shared)
   boost::thread::yield();
```

And at some point the other thread will call:

```
shared.reset();
```

My question is whether or not I need to declare the shared pointer as `volatile` to prevent the compiler from optimizing the call to `shared.operator bool()` out of the loop and never detecting the change?  I know that if I were simply looping on a variable, waiting for it to reach 0 I would need `volatile`, but I'm not sure if `boost::shared_ptr` is implemented in such a way that it is not necessary here.

EDIT: I'm fully aware that condition variables can be used to solve this problem in a different way.  But in this case, the busy loop is very uncommon and contending for the lock on the condition variable is an overhead we would rather not incur.

Comment: Oh boy.  Here we go...

Comment: Please, don't. Stop that now. There is a huge number of reasons to not do what you are trying to do. Then, take a good read at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref

Comment: @JaredC:  Please take a look at [this][1], [this][2] and [this][3] for more information about `volatile`   [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168735/is-this-rule-about-volatile-usage-strict
  [2]: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136900/what-rules-does-compiler-have-to-follow-when-dealing-with-volatile-memory-locatio

Comment: @JaredC:  And this, probably first of all:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading

Comment: "condition variable is an overhead" have you measured it? It looks like premature optimization.

Comment: @John: In fact the answer to the question of that last link ("`volatile` is useless") seems to answer this question as well.

Comment: @ybung We are in the process of removing locks from this performance sensitive section of code, so we have determined their overhead.  This code gets executed 10000+ times per second, so we're trying to streamline it.

Comment: @JaredC:  Given your motivations, please bear in mind that the true purpose of `volatile` is to suppress optimizations.  This seems to be the exact opposite of the reason you may be trying to use it.

Comment: @John: Thanks for the links and input.  I am going to review those articles (and their links (and their links)) to completely understand volatile.  Sorry to post on a such a sore topic.

Comment: @JaredC:  Don't apologize.  This is just my personal soapbox topic.  It is an excellent question.  In fact your question has prompted us (in C++ chat) to write a FAQ on the subject.

Answer (score 7):

### Rant 1:

That code probably won't do what you think it will.  When you write code like that, you're introducing a [data race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) into your code.  **This is almost certainly a bug** that will result in your program [non-deterministically failing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug).

Data structures (including shared_ptr) are generally not meant to be accessed concurrently.  Do not modify the same structure at the same time in more than one thread.  That could corrupt the structure.  Do not modify it in one thread and read it in another thread.  The reader could see inconsistent data.   *Probably* multiple threads can read it at the same time.

If you think you really want to do some of the above, find out if the data structure allows some of these behaviors in a section probably titled "Thread Safety."  If it does allow them, take a second look at whether your performance *really* needs this, and then use it.  (The documentation on [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) does NOT allow what you're doing.)

### Rant 2:

Now, for a higher-level concern, you probably shouldn't be doing thread synchronization by waiting for a pointer to be set to NULL.  Really, look at condition variables, barriers, or futures as a way of getting one thread to wait until another is finished with something.  It's a nicer interface, and whoever looks at your code next (that includes you in 6 months) will thank you.

I know you're concerned about the performance cost of real synchronization.  Don't worry about this.  It'll be fine.  If you're worried about lock contention, use barriers or futures, which don't have a big shared lock to contend for.

Caveat: there is a time for writing code that avoids locks at all cost.  But unless you're looking at profiler data that says your synch ops are too slow for your target workload, this isn't the time.

### Rant 3:

I hope that `shared` in your example is global.  Otherwise, you have multiple threads with local references to the same `shared_ptr` that points to the real object you're interested in.  It kind of defeats the purpose of having a reference-counted pointer.  Just please tell me it's global.

Comment: Rant3: shared is a global variable, yes.  Rant2: We are at the point of optimization, which is why I am removing locks in this code section in the first place. Rant1: This is the most valid argument I've heard for not doing this, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What you actually should do is to use [condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref). Busy waits are **evil**.

Edit: also depending on your task, [futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) may be even cleaner way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I agree usually, but in this case the loop should almost never get executed, so we've decided that busy looping is better than contending for the lock.

Comment: Then you can easily check once before acquiring the lock, then you almost never will acquire the lock. Still it's not an excuse to busy wait. Without lock you can't guarantee that shared remains empty after the loop.

Comment: @JaredC:  If the loop almost never gets executed then the lock will almost never be contended.

Comment: JaredC: Busy looping is never ( * ) better than using a monitor, periode. (Note: ( * ) in some cases, it may actually be better, namely, in kernel code in non-battery-powered embedded systems, but that most probably is not your case).

Comment: @ybung, checking once before looping would still require the thread calling reset() to acquire the lock always.

Comment: @JaredC: no. you *always* call condVar.notify_all() without a lock.

Comment: @ybung, But then there is a race condition that the the waiting thread might not actually be waiting YET, but have already seen its condition as false.  Then, the reset() call happens and the notify_all() wakes up exactly no one.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JaredC: oops, my mistake. You're right here.