# Problems with STL as a static volatile member

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile something like this:

```
#include <list>

class thread
{
public:
 static volatile std::list<thread *> threadList;    //This is also protected by a mutex
};
volatile std::list<thread *> thread::threadList;

void main()
{
 thread A;
 thread::threadList.push_back(&A);
 thread::threadList.remove(&A);
}
```

I get these errors when trying to compile:

```
test.cpp(14): error C2663: 'std::list::push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
          with
          [
              _Ty=thread *
          ]
test.cpp(15): error C2662: 'std::list::remove' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'volatile std::list' to 'std::list &'
          with
          [
              _Ty=thread *
          ]
          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: fixed some formatting errors with < and >
EDIT2: threadList is protected by a mutex, I just didn't put it here for simplicity

Comment: I'm betting he wants a list of all c++0x or boost `thread` s he has and he wants the container holding them to be synchronized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove volatile and remove the problem. So for the real answer, it might help if you explain why you need to volatile, and what it is intended to mean here. It won't make the whole list be treated as volatile.

See also [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136900/what-rules-does-compiler-have-to-follow-when-dealing-with-volatile-memory-locatio/4137088#4137088)

Comment: I'm using volatile because the list will be used by multiple threads. Also this code is simplified; my actual code has the list protected by a mutex. Now that I think about it, would volatile even make a difference in that case?

Comment: @Mark: No.  If you have a lock around it, `volatile` is not needed for simple access protection.

Comment: @Mark- Volatile won't make the `vector` thread-safe.  You'll need to use explicit locks.  Usually, `volatile` means "don't optimize reads and writes of this value because it might be changed from some other space," not "prevent multiple threads from touching this variable."

Comment: I'm also using volatile with the list because I'm afraid some thread will change it, but the change will go unnoticed by other threads due to the compiler over optimizing

Comment: @Mark:  That's why you need to use a lock to synchronize access to the `vector`.  `volatile` does not do whatever you think it does.  You can't use it to guarantee anything in multithreading.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `volatile` is possibly the least understood keyword, and its more than likely **NOT** doing what you think it is.  I learned this the [hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662482/c-volatile-required-when-spinning-on-boostshared-ptr-operator-bool).

That being said, The issue is that `volatile` can also be used as a qualifier on functions to ensure that they're called in the correct context.  The `push_back()` function is not declared with the `volatile` qualifier, so calling it on a `volatile` object is not valid.  A nonvolatile member function can only be called for a nonvolatile object.

Answer (score 2):

Using g++ to compile this gives

> test.cpp:13: error: passing ‘volatile
>   std::list >’ as ‘this’
>   argument of ‘void std::list<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = thread*, _Alloc = std::allocator]’ discards
>   qualifiers
>   ...

The `discards qualifiers` is your hint. The function `list::push_back` cannot be called on `const` or `volatile` instances.

One way to do this:

- make the list private
- create a private static mutex
- create a static public function that `add` and `remove`
- in `add` and `remove` acquire the lock, then add or remove from the list