# How to make a derived class function as a thread's start routine?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, pthreads

Hi I have the following C++ code,

I have MyThread class in the thread.h file

```
class MyThread
{ 
    public:
       void start();
       virtual void* task() = 0;
};
```

I have worker class in the worker.h file

```
class Worker : public MyThread
{
    virtual ~Worker();
    virtual void* task();   // I have implementation in worker.cpp
};
```

Have used `pthread_create()` in the `start()` in `thread.cpp` file for creating a thread and I want to make the `task()` routine defined in the w`orker.cpp` as the start routine . So how can I do that ? What should I pass as the parameter to the start routine in `pthread_create` ?

I have tried this but it gives an error:

```
pthread_create(&(this->threadId),&(this->attr),(void *)task,NULL);
```

Comment: Do you really want to use C++11 like your tag suggests? In that case you can dump pthread and use the built-in threads.

Comment: Pointer to class-member function actually isn't pointer to function. And +1 for built-in threads.

Comment: @KillianDS, latest official mingw build, as far as I know, build with thread support desibled.

Comment: I hope this [this answher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956759/c11-stdthread-inside-a-class-executing-a-function-member-with-thread-initia) helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use member function as a thread function. You can only use free functions or static member functions, *but* you can pass arbitrary void* argument to that function and you can pass pointer to `this` as that argument, that allows you to call member function inside that function:

```
class MyThread
{ 
    public:
       void start();
       virtual void* task() = 0;

       static void * thread_routine(void* pthis)
       {
            MyThread* t = static_cast<MyThread*>(pthis);
            t->task();
            return 0;
       }
};
```

Then you launch your thread like this

```
void MyThread::start()
{
    pthread_create(&(this->threadId),&(this->attr),thread_routine, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use task() as start routine for the thread because it is a member function instead of a free function, like the expected signature void *(*start_routine)(void*). (also, it doesn't have the pointer to void parameter)

I would just create a wrapper and have it as the start routine, something like this:

```
void *wrapper(void *data)
{
    Worker worker;
    worker.task();

}
```