# std::atomic<T> and std::atomic_flag usage in Interrupt Handlers

Tags: c++, embedded, atomic, interrupt

Can a `std::atomic<T>` that is verified to be lock free or a `std::atomic_flag` safely be used in an Interrupt Service Handler (ISR) to pass a message/flag/indicator from Interrupt Context to another thread or process?

I'm defining `std::atomic<T>` as lock free if `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` is true or if  `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free` is checked for each instance of `std::atomic<T>`.

The standard does not mention any usage of interrupts in the atomic documentation. This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2479474/5374468) compares volatile for interrupts and std::atomic for inter-thread communication.

Comment: The standard doesn't consider the existence of interrupts, but it does consider the existence of signals, which behave effectively in the same way. And for signals this use of lock-free atomics is permitted and intended.

Comment: Do you have any context/reference you can point me to about why the standard doesn't consider the existence of interrupts?

Comment: I don't have a reference for a rationale. You would probably need to start looking in some early C++ standard committee documents for that. In a hosted environment you usually don't have interrupts, only signals. So that only leaves freestanding environments and there a lot of behavior will be platform-specific anyway. Or the abstract notion of signals is supposed to cover interrupts as well. The C standard several times seems to equate signals with interrupts, e.g. in 5.2.3.

Comment: I removed the tags. I was going for modern C++ but couldn't find such a tag. Our project uses a mix of C++11, 14, and 17 across different applications and toolchains.

Comment: Ok, so to get an answer that works for all those, then tag it C++11. It helps people to  constrain their answers to what will work in all your mixes.

Comment: @Panda - We can find documents that have been proposed for inclusion in the standard. But there is definitely no documentation for what has *not* been proposed.

Comment: "_to another thread or process_": Other processes are also not a concept in the standard. Other threads are and communicating with another thread in a signal handler, or the thread that was interrupted by the signal handler, via lock-free atomic is safe. The requirements for signal handlers, which in my opinion should directly translate to interrupts, can be found in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal.

Comment: @user17732522: Other processes aren't *formally* part of the ISO C++ standard, but a note does mention that lock-free atomics *should* be address-free so they work in shared memory between processes.  (That is in fact the case in real implementations, and a Deathstation 9000 would have to make an effort to break that.)  And yeah, interrupts work the same in practice as signal handlers would, in terms of running asynchronously but within a thread's context.